# How to list the title and date of purchase of all books purchased during the first half of the year

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to get the books that was purchased first half year (Jan-Jun).

I tried this query

```
select title, purchase_date
from books
where purchase_date between '1992-01-01' and '2005-06-30'
```

but I get all the books, I don't want to change the year only the months but I don't know how.

Comment: see date_part() function

Comment: Column purchase_date data type?

Answer (score 1):

Use the ANSI standard `extract()` function:

```
select title, purchase_date
from books
where extract(month from purchase_date) between 1 and 6;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want all books from all years but just those sold Jan to June then use

```
SELECT title, purchase_date
FROM books
WHERE date_part('month',purchase_date) BETWEEN 1 and 6
```

Comment: I't didn't work, I't said i dont have any column namned mm

Comment: Sorry, coded for SQL, use date_part('month',purchase_date)

Answer (score -1):

If the purchase_date is a date type column then your query should work fine but if purhcase_date is datetime then you need to append time in where clause of the query

```
select title, purchase_date
from books
where purchase_date between '2005-06-30 00:00:00' and '2005-06-30 11:59:59'
```

Comment: Hi ChrisM, I have guided him about how to to query according to data types. Thanks for your response.